# Convert Pipe Separated string to a Comma Separated format in c #

Tags: string, c#-4.0

My Input String is in the below format :

```
"USA||CANADA||RUSSIA'S||AUSTRALIA"
```

Kindly help me to get the Output String in the below format in c# :

```
" 'USA','CANADA','RUSSIA''S','AUSTRALIA' "
```

I have tried with the following code like :

```
var string ="USA||CANADA||RUSSIA'S||AUSTRALIA";   
string[] countries =string.Split(new string[] "||" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  
string result = "'" + string.Join("','", countries) + "'";
```

I am getting the output as

```
" 'USA','CANADA','RUSSIA'S','AUSTRALIA' "
```

But I want one more Apostrophe with Russia i.e Russia''s.

Please help

Comment: Please post what you tried and what challenges you faced on your attempt

Comment: @Lijo-Updated the post.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string[] countries = "USA||CANADA||RUSSIA'S||AUSTRALIA".Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string result = "'" + string.Join("','", countries) + "'";
```

**Update:**

Use this one:

```
string[] countries = "USA||CANADA||RUSSIA'S||AUSTRALIA".Replace("'", "\"").Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string result = "'" + string.Join("','", countries) + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.I have tried this.But still I am having an issue.I have explained the issue in the post itself.Thanks again for your help.